# Why does this code give the error "cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘char*&’ to an rvalue of type ‘char*’"

Tags: c++

Why does the following code give this error:

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'char*&' to an rvalue of type 'char*'

```cpp
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string p {"Test string"};
    auto &r = p.data();
    return 0;
}
```

The type of the pointer returned by `std::string::data` is `char *`. And the type of variable `r` is `char *&`. So why, in this case, the type of `char *` cannot be referenced by a type of `char *`?

Comment: Same reason you can't do `int& a = 5`.

Comment: The type of pointer returned by`std::string::data` is `const char*` and not `char *`

Comment: @DebarghaRoy Only until C++17. Since then, there are [both versions are provided](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.accessors).

Comment: @DanielLangr you're correct. But I specified it wrt to C++11. I'm not sure if all compilers support C++17 properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that the C++ standard doesn't allow non-const references to bind to temporaries, and `std::string::data` returns a pointer by value. Only `const` reference can do that, and prolong the life of the temporary object.

In your case you either need to make your reference const.

```cpp
const auto& r = p.data();
```

Or better, just create a variable that will store the pointer for you, as pointers are cheap to copy around.

```cpp
const char* r = p.data();
```

Comment: Note that it might not be a good idea to store the result of `std::string::data` since it can easily be invalidated when the string is modified.

Comment: Also, `auto r = p.data()` works fine, cause `auto` is able to initialize pointers to constants as well.